# Is AJAX only for dynamic content or can it also create buttons, and change css properties?

Tags: ajax

I was wondering, is Ajax only for dynamic content update or can it also, say, create a few buttons in a given div depending on what action a user chooses in another div? For example, if the login page and first page look very similar by only a few buttons, once proper login credentials are entered, can I use Ajax to make the other three buttons appear once logged in properly, rather than going to a whole another web page that has those buttons hard coded in the html/css? If this is possible, I'll take pointers to any tutorials. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, Ajax can be used for both. You may want to read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is just for creating HTTP requests using javascript, in order to prevent full page requests.

What you can do is to process the login request using AJAX and then, depending on the response you send, to display an error or update the DOM with the logged in interface.

If you just want to change the DOM, you use javascript directly (jquery would help) but no AJAX is needed.

Comment: So I use Ajax for login credential processing and use jquery to modify the visuals? as in button's appearing on the "logged in" screen? Thanks for clarification. I am totally new to this.

Comment: Sure, take a look on jQuery documentation to see all you can do with it, including AJAX requests: http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/